# Neural Network, dependence among outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, independence

Is there a way to train a neural network in the following manner:

You have $n$ observations in the training set.

The neural net will start with random weights, and produce $n$ outputs. I want to then apply a function, $f$, on these $n$ outputs. $f$ will output a single real valued number $\alpha$. The goal of the neural net is to then maximize $\alpha$.

That is, I don't care what the neural net outputs for any single observation. I want it to maximize some property of the outputs as a whole (e.g. I want to maximize the variance of the outputs).

Are there neural networks like this, or other techniques for what I am looking for?

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: You can use genetic algorithm for optimization. Just approach it as any other optimization problem, where you have an output you'd like to maximize.

Comment: sashkello, You use GAs to optimize over a neural network structure? Had no idea, gotta look into this!

Comment: This is what I usually do with customized NN's, maybe there could be better ways, but always worked for me.

Comment: What is your dataset and what are you trying to do with $n$, $f$ and $\alpha$. From a training standpoint, this sounds like you want sparsity.

Comment: Hey Jacob, I want the "shape" of the output to have a certain form. That is, if I plot $i$ against the output, $o_i$, for each observation $i$, I want that plot to have a certain shape. So the idea was to take the entire set of the output from the NN, subtract that from the desired shape, and feed that back into the NN, so that the entire set of the output NN starts to approximate the desired shape.

Comment: I'm missing what is different here. You have some function, $f$, which you want to maximize (equivalently minimize $-f$). How is this different then optimizing a loss function? Also why would you want to maximize variance? Wouldn't you just end up with some degenerate solution like push the output for half the inputs to $+\infty$ and the other half to $-\infty$?

Comment: @ssdecontrol the OP has not been around since shortly after this question was asked, and the question itself is not fully clear*. If you have something in mind, you might be better off posting a new question. (*In the simplest instance where their function $f$ is a [summation over the training examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator), the problem is just the standard NN training problem. Technically this may even be true for general $f$, though the standard stochastic gradient descent may not be appropriate in that case. The only difference is not caring about generalization error)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 that's a good point. I don't have anything in particular in mind, I just figured this was the kind of thing someone would come along and ask about, then leave disappointed having found nothing

Comment: @ssdecontrol I also feel that the question is not very clear - to the extent that I would be tempted to downvote it, if not for your bounty. I would suggest that you try to edit this Q as much as possible to make it clear as you see fit. The OP has left anyway.

Comment: CC to @GeoMatt22.

Comment: @amoeba eh, i'm happy to just let the bounty expire. I'm not really attached to that 100 rep. Feel free to downvote

Comment: @ssdecontrol I will not downvote as long as your bounty runs, but I will not upvote either :-)

Comment: Some new remark: if such an optimization technique exists, what will it find? I think it will find rather trivial solutions. For example, it could ignore the input of the training set and output $n$ fixed values that maximize $f$.

Comment: I like Eric Wan's diagrammatic method.  It allows decent gradient determination for arbitrary networks without chain rule.  It is clean.  I would use it after training to determine which sub-nodes drive "a" and then instead of gradient descent, I could iterate through gradient ascent.

Answer (score 2):

> The neural net will start with random weights, and produce $n$ outputs. I want to then apply a function, $f$, on these $n$ outputs. $f$ will output a single real valued number $\alpha$. The goal of the neural net is to then maximize $\alpha$.

This means that the training set is not used. The problem is just maximizing $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ given $x_1, ..., x_n$. There exist a fair amount of literature on that topic, the choice of technique depending on $f$: [Mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it but with some modification to your proposed algorithm. In order to train your network, you need to know error (which you are computing), but also the direction of the error (derivative) with respect to the activity of the neuron and the weight. So you need to know if the error would increase or decrease if you change the weight.

So you can do

1. compute outputs for all your samples (and save activations of the neurons for each sample)
2. compute where should each of your sample move, to minimize your custom criterion.
3. us this as the error term in your training and update your weights accordingly

Another question is however if the neural network is the right tool to do it. For example if you want to find projection that would maximize variance, (nonlinear) PCA might be better.

**Edit:**
Although after bounty period, but here is an example hacky code that does that.

This is a neural network trained to create outputs that are equally distant from each other.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import neural_network

def get_new_targets(x):
    """
    Function to get points that are in the middle of the neighbouring points"""
    try:
        x = [e[1] for e in x]
    except:
        pass
    enumerated_x = [e for e in enumerate(x)]
    enumerated_x.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    targets = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(enumerated_x):
        previous_sample, next_sample = 0, 0
#        current_sample =  enumerated_x[i][1]
        if i == 0:
            previous_sample = 0
        else:
            previous_sample = enumerated_x[i-1][1]
        if i == len(enumerated_x)-1:
            next_sample = 50
        else:            
            next_sample = enumerated_x[i+1][1]            
        target = (previous_sample + next_sample)/2. 
        targets.append(target)        
    targets_in_order = sorted([(enum[0], t) for enum, t in zip(enumerated_x, targets)])
    targets_in_order = [e[1] for e in targets_in_order]
    return np.array(targets_in_order)



# create training data
# in this example we care only about one axis
X = np.array([[0,3], [0,4], [0,10], [0,15], [0,35], [0,36] ,[0,50]])
# create initial targers. This will change every epoch
Y = get_new_targets(X)

preds = [] # save predictions
epochs = []

# warm start True and max_iter 1 to simulate batch training
clf = neural_network.MLPRegressor(max_iter=1, warm_start=True, alpha=0.005, 
                                  hidden_layer_sizes=(50,), activation='logistic')

for i in range(4000): # for each epoch
    # since warms_start=True it will reuse weights from previous epoch
    clf.fit(X, Y) 
    predictions =  clf.predict(X) 
    Y = get_new_targets(predictions)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        pred = clf.predict(X)        
        preds.append([pred])
        epochs.append(i)
```

Plots that show that it kindof worked, but not really

[image]
[image]